# Why does my Backbone model hasChanged() always return false?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Given the following snippet:

```
var m = new Backbone.Model({
    name: 'joshua'
});

m.set('name', 'something else');
```

If I now call `m.hasChanged()` or `m.hasChanged('name')` I get `false`. **Why?** My understanding is that both of these should return `true`.

`m.changedAttributes()` also returns false.

Here is a fiddle that illustrates what I'm doing, and expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/88/

**EDIT:**  It seems that unless you pass `{ silent: true; }` to the `set()` method then it will fire the `change` event on your model which clears out the `changedAttributes()`, etc. Essentially these properties only track changes since the last time the `change` event was triggered.

I read that in the documentation but didn't really understand it at first.

This doesn't seem very useful to me. I would appreciate any explanation of why this works the way it does and the best way to achieve the result I want. (Passing around `{silent: true; }` and giving up usage of the `change` event seems like a waste.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unless you pass `{ silent: true; }` to the `set()` method then it will fire the `change` event on your model which clears out the `changedAttributes()`, etc. Essentially these properties only track changes since the last time the `change` event was triggered.

So the answer is to call this instead:

```
m.set('name', 'something else', {silent: true})
```

Comment: Ah ha. I made a `save()` method for collections that sends a batch of models and returns. Was wondering why hasChanged() didn't seem to do anything. :-) Thanks!

Comment: This is no longer true in newer versions of Backbone; see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

This post is premised on the previous behavior of older versions of Backbone.  `hasChanged` *does now* ([as of 0.9.10](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2227#issuecomment-12957672)) always returns `true` after `set(..)` is called.  The `silent` flag no longer has any effect.

This is confusingly masked in the jsfiddle linked in the question which uses a CDN-hosted copy of backbone.js which always uses the latest version.  Here's some updated jsfiddles showing the change in behavior:

- [jsfiddle using Backbone 0.9.2](http://jsfiddle.net/nwZyx/)
- [jsfiddle using Backbone 0.9.10](http://jsfiddle.net/bE5H7/)

Answer (score -7):

`Model.set()` takes an attributes hash as the first argument. Try `m.set({'name': 'something else'});`. Doing `m.set('name', 'something')` doesn't set 'name', so it never triggers the `change` event and your call to `hasChanged()` returns `false`. You can always inspect the current value of the attributes hash by logging out `m.attributes` - though accessing and manipulating it directly isn't recommended as none of the change events will fire that way.

Comment: Wrong. `Model.set()` supports both a hash and a single attribute like I am using. The attribute is being set, as you can see in [this slightly expanded fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2raK/1/). This is also illustrated [in the Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).

Comment: Sorry about that, should have read closer. What is it exactly that you're trying to do? You could just bind to the model `change` event. That way you can check specific attributes for change w/ `hasChanged(attr)` (to see if you need to update a certain part of the view). I edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2raK/4/) to illustrate this.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to get the list of properties that have changed since the model was saved. For now I'm passing `{silent:true}` around and then checking the `changedAttributes()`. This is working exactly like I need, I just expected Backbone to work more like the traditional `isDirty` flag in a data model.

Comment: Ah, seems like that's the solution then, since `save` also fires a `change` event. [Looks like](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged) `hasChanged`, and others are meant specifically for change events.